# Fetch all rows until a special one matched

Tags: mysql, sql, fetch

I have a Log in a MySql DB and now I would use it to check sessions, so i want to fetch all rows before "type 3" not more.

```
+--------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+------+
| id     | username    | date                | address   | success | type |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+------+
| 110771 | test        | 2013-08-02 11:17:54 | 127.0.0.1 |       1 |    5 |
| 110772 | test        | 2013-08-02 11:18:03 | 127.0.0.1 |       1 |    3 |
| 110773 | test        | 2013-08-02 11:18:13 | 127.0.0.1 |       1 |    7 |
| 110774 | test        | 2013-08-02 11:18:17 | 127.0.0.1 |       1 |    5 |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+------+
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT *
FROM logTable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM logTable b
    WHERE b.date <= a.date
    AND b.type = 3
)
```